# Convert a method into a promise : Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, nodemailer

I have the following Nodejs method that I want to call and execute a `.then` function on. I am not sure how to write this method so that I can use the `.then()` method on it.

I have the `sendEmail` method in `nodemailer.js` that I want to call in my `app.js` and execute the `.then()` method on. It currently gives me the error:

> nodeMailer.sendEmail().then(function ...
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

I understand this is because my method does not return a promise. I am not sure how to write this method to return a promise while it retains its original functionality.

### nodemailer.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://********');   
var mytext="my new text";

var mailOptions ={
    from: '"Reviews"<Reviews@reviews.com>', // sender address
    to: 'Someone@something.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Test', // Subject line
    text: '', // plaintext body
    }

module.exports = {
    mailOptions:mailOptions,
    sendEmail: function() {
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
            if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
               } else {
                    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
               }
        })
    }
}
```

Calling the above in `app.js` gives the error mentioned above

### app.js

```
var nodeMailer = require('./nodeMailer')
var cron = require('cron');

var cronJob1 = cron.job("*/30 * * * * *", function(){
    Model.find(query,function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something Broke!' });
        } else {
            nodeMailer.mailOptions.text =  JSON.stringify(results);
            nodeMailer.sendEmail().then(function(){
                Model.findAndUpdate(query,  { $set: { "email": true }}, 
                    function(err, resp){
                        console.log(resp, "successfully updated")
                    })
            });
        }
    });
}); 
cronJob1.start();
```

Comment: Fixed Code indent, removed filler text, minor text edits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [nodemailer docs](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/README.md#), if you leave out the callback in your `sendMail` call, it will return a `Promise`. So just return that.

```
sendEmail: function() { 
  return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
  .then(
    function(info) { 
      console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response); 
    },
    function(error){
      console.log(error); 
    }
  );
}
```